# Array row calculations

Tags: arrays, r

I have the following table:

DATA:

```
Lines <- "  ID  MeasureX    MeasureY        x1  x2  x3  x4  x5
             1      1         1             1   1   1   1   1
             2      1         1             0   1   1   1   1      
             3      1         1             1   2   3   3   3"

 DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE, as.is = TRUE)
```

What i would like to achieve is :

1. Create 5 columns(r1-r5)

   which is the division of each column x1-x5 with MeasureX (example x1/measurex, x2/measurex etc.)
2. Create 5 columns(p1-p5)

   which is the division of each column x1-x5 with number 1-5 (the number of xcolumns) example x1/1, x2/2 etc.

MeasureY is irrelevant for now, the end product would be the ID and columns r1-r5 and p1-p5, is this feasible?

In SAS i would go with something like this:

```
data test6;
set test5;
array x {5} x1- x5;
array r{5} r1 - r5;
array p{5} p1 - p5;
do i=1 to 5;
    r{i}    = x{i}/MeasureX;
    p{i} = x{i}/(i);
    end;
```

The reason would be to have more dynamic beacuse the number of columns could change in the future.

Comment: Anything you've already tried yourself? Why did it not work?

Comment: Yes, it is feasible.  What help are you looking for with regards to feasibility or execution?

Comment: This won't be hard for you. Here's a start: `DF$r1 <- DF$x1 / DF$MeasureX`

Comment: I have tried this in SAS but i am facing difficulty applying the logic in R, so I am wondering if there are any suggestions in how to do it in R

Comment: There are many, but on SO some of your own effort in solving the problem is always appreciated (this is not a code-writing/translating service).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Argument recycling allows you do do element-wise division with a constant vector. The tricky part was extracting the digits from the column names. I then repeated each of the digits by the number of rows to do the second division-task.

```
DF[ ,paste0("r", 1:5)] <- DF[ , grep("x", names(DF) )]/ DF$MeasureX

DF[ ,paste0("p", 1:5)] <- DF[ , grep("x", names(DF) )]/   # element-wise division
                          rep( as.numeric( sub("\\D","",names(DF)[ # remove non-digits
                                         grep("x", names(DF))]  #returns only 'x'-cols
                              ) ), each=nrow(DF) ) # make them as long as needed
#-------------
> DF
  ID MeasureX MeasureY x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 r1 r2 r3 r4 r5 p1  p2        p3   p4  p5
1  1        1        1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1 0.5 0.3333333 0.25 0.2
2  2        1        1  0  1  1  1  1  0  1  1  1  1  0 0.5 0.3333333 0.25 0.2
3  3        1        1  1  2  3  3  3  1  2  3  3  3  1 1.0 1.0000000 0.75 0.6
```

This could be greatly simplified if you already know the sequence vector for the second division task would be 1-5, but this was designed to allow "gaps" in the sequence for column names and still use the digit information in the names as the divisor. (You were not entirely clear about what situations this code would be used in.)  The construct of r{1-5} in SAS is mimicked by `[ , paste0('r', 1:5)]`. SAS is a macro language and sometimes experienced users have trouble figuring out how to make R behave like one. Generally it takes a while to lose the for-loop mentality and begin using R as a functional language.

Comment: You are right about that, i have noticed that when wanting to loop, lets say predictive models  based on different type of parameters every time with different samples. It can get messy with all the lists that have to be declared before running the loop, this has been the biggest challenge in transitioning from SAS to R for me because the reality is that most of the times the code has to be dynamic and you pick up that habit due to that SAS is a macro language. Thank you very much for your solution provided, nice work.

Comment: If you find code useful, the SO convention is to give it an upvote. Doesn't matter much to me anymore since I'm clearly addicted to answering R questions, but you might start seeing people ignore your questions if you don't "play the game".

Comment: no worries it was my intention anyways, thank you again for your time on this

Answer (score 2):

An alternative with the `data.table` package:

```
cols <- names(df[c(4:8)])

library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, (paste0("r",1:5)) := .SD / df$MeasureX, by = ID, .SDcols = cols
          ][, (paste0("p",1:5)) := .SD / 1:5, by = ID, .SDcols = cols]
```

which results in:

```
> df
   ID MeasureX MeasureY x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 r1 r2 r3 r4 r5 p1  p2        p3   p4  p5
1:  1        1        1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1 0.5 0.3333333 0.25 0.2
2:  2        1        1  0  1  1  1  1  0  1  1  1  1  0 0.5 0.3333333 0.25 0.2
3:  3        1        1  1  2  3  3  3  1  2  3  3  3  1 1.0 1.0000000 0.75 0.6
```

Answer (score 1):

You could put together a nifty loop or apply to do this, but here it is explicitly:

```
# Handling the "r" columns.
DF$r1 <- DF$x1 / DF$MeasureX
DF$r2 <- DF$x2 / DF$MeasureX
DF$r3 <- DF$x3 / DF$MeasureX
DF$r4 <- DF$x4 / DF$MeasureX
DF$r5 <- DF$x5 / DF$MeasureX

# Handling the "p" columns.
DF$p1 <- DF$x1 / 1
DF$p2 <- DF$x2 / 2
DF$p3 <- DF$x3 / 3
DF$p4 <- DF$x4 / 4
DF$p5 <- DF$x5 / 5

# Taking only the columns we want.
FinalDF <- DF[, c("ID", "r1", "r2", "r3", "r4", "r5", "p1", "p2", "p3", "p4", "p5")]
```

Just noting that this is pretty straightforward matrix manipulation that you definitely could have found elsewhere. Perhaps you're new to R, but still put a little more effort in next time. If you are new to R, it's definitely worth the time to look up some basic R coding tutorial or video.

Comment: This could be achieved without a loop/typing everything by doing something like `result_r <- DF[,paste0("x",1:5)]/DF$MeasureX`and then changing the columns.

Comment: Yeah, I know. I just wanted to keep it simple and explicit since OP seems like he's new to R.

Comment: You are right this type of calculation is easy, it is my fault though that i wasnt clear in my enquiry. The 5 columns here could be 25 in the future so writting all the statements is not effective then codewise, i have edited in the question how it would go in SAS
Sorry again for leaving that out

Comment: That's fine, use the solution above mine that BondedDust posted for better scale for the future.